# Powershell: Get path of last alphanumerically sorted file in a directory

Tags: powershell, path, alphanumeric

I have a directory with the following files:

1. Program-3.0.79.J1231.exe
2. Program-3.0.79.J1230.exe
3. Program-3.0.79.J1229.exe
4. Program-3.0.79.J1228.exe
5. etc...

These files will keep updating every few weeks. For example Program-3.0.79.J1232.exe will automatically be put in this directory in a week or two

Using Power Shell,  how would I easily go about getting the path of the latest (NOT WITH last modified) file added. Preferably via alphanumeric sorting

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes with the "last modified" approach! But I made some silly clicks and it changed a file 3 versions off to be the latest...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fairly simple:

`((Gci 'C:\Myfolder' | sort-object name)[-1]).fullname`

The `[-1`] index means "last item in the array".

Comment: sure is a alphanumerical sort?

Comment: @Christian feel free to try it.  Worked for me.

Comment: tryed with 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt and 10.txt, got 3.txt!?!

Comment: @Christian - do you know how alphanumeric sorting works?  3>1 so it shows up as last.  It's based on characters not numeric values.

Comment: @jnk - yes, I was thinking for a numerical sort! sorry for the inappropriate comments!

Comment: @Christian no problem, it doesn't make much sense unless you are a computer sometimes :)

Comment: @JNK Oh right sorry.. but how do I find the latest and only of a specific file type??

Comment: @MaxAlexander `gci 'c:\myfolder' -filter '*.txt'`

Answer (score 6):

Here's another version that also filters out folders in case they exist in the path:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | `
 Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | `
  Sort-Object Name | `
   Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks! I might need the alternate version. Never know!

Answer (score 0):

I actually think `Get-ChildItem` already returns an alphanumerically sorted list:

```
(ls Program*)[-1]
```

Not sure if that applies in your particular case though (`3.0.8` would be after `3.0.79` etc.)